# Granite devices Ionicube

Tags: motor

Is it possible to enable/disable the 4 Ioni drives mounted in Ionicube individually?  It appears with IoniCube that enable/disable applies to all Ioni drives simultaneously.  However, Ionicube 1X does appear to have enable/disable for individual Ioni drives.  Can you confirm?

I wish to control the enable/disable state of each Ioni drive separately.  And if possible to do this on IoniCube.

Most grateful for your help!

Best wishes,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

The IONICUBE has global enable and STO inputs, so all IONI drives are enabled/disabled simultaneously. And thus, enabling a single IONI drive is not possible.

The IONICUBE 1X only hosts a single IONI drive, and thus it's enable and STO inputs control only that drive.